# Vector IF in Fortran possible?

Tags: fortran, vectorization

Assume you have two arrays of equal dimension and want to construct a larger one which holds the maximum. Of course you use the in-built max and you don't need an explicite index. But now assume the new number is not computable by a vectorizable construct and you have to compute an if statement inside a do loop for each index. The compiler can parallelize that anyway, I bet (the result shall just depend on the current loop index). But is a construct like IF (a(:).EQ.b(:)) THEN c(:)=... without explicite index possible?

Comment: I've no idea whether it's what you're interested in (perhaps you could create a example with expected input/output?), but are you aware of the `where` statement/construct?

Comment: Yes, I think you are asking for the `WHERE` construct.

Comment: Probably WHERE, but maybe MERGE  is another possibility?

Comment: WHERE looks good! (In fact, I look for the element with the highest frequency in an array, but the array is rather small, where the elements can be large, so tallying in an indexed array is ineffective.)